# Uso de la propiedad CSS background-img en Laravel

Tags: css, laravel, html5

Estoy intentando aplicar un estilo de `background-img` a mi imagen en `Laravel`:

HTML:

```
<img src="{{ asset("assets/img/img.jpeg") }}" alt="img">
```

CSS:

```
img::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('../assets/img/splash.jpg');
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
```

El problema es que en los estilos del **selector** `::before` no se me aplica su bg-image. ¿Existe alguna forma de lograr el resultado?

Comment: En plan tienes algun ejemplo visual? Es algo asi como una imagen encima de otra ? como un splash?

Comment: exacto es una imagen encima de otra como una mascara. La imagen que va encima se transparenta y se ve la de abajo aplicando el mix-blend-mode. Intento replicar este ejumplo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lBK_kh4iCAQ

Answer (score 0):

Vale según el video que me has mandado, lo he probado y va.

1. Usa un `div` o una etiqueta como `section`, `aside`... y no pongas el `img` para hacerlo.

   `<div></div>`
2. Ahora al div le aplicas los estilos que dice, sobre todo el de la imagen para que la cargue como fondo en el div (no verás nada en la pantalla porque no coge ninguna imagen, no encuentra imágenes online así de rápido. Así que úsalo en tu código. Yo con unas mías si funciono. No perfecto, luego le das tus detalles, básicamente es igual que el vídeo que pasaste.

```css
div {
position: relative;
widht: 100%;
min-height: 100vh;
background: url(tu imagen de atras);
background-size: cover;
}

div:before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: url("Tu imagen superpuesta");
background-size: 1800px;
background-position: center;
mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Lo que he visto es que tu le insertas la imagen desde el `img` y eso, que yo sepa no lo hará un fondo. Si se usa fondo de normal se usa un `div` u otra etiqueta y se le da en `css` el fondo.
Ten en cuenta el formato de imagen que uses para poner encima, puede que tape entero. En el video son `jpg` pero blanco y negro únicamente.

Comprueba que te va enlazando imágenes reales jaja y toquetea los valores como `vh` y demás para ir ajustándolo como prefieras. Espero haberte ayudado.